# My input value is not a number I inserted

Tags: c#

I try to make a multiplier. When I insert number 5, it magically turns to 53. When number 2, it will be 50. Can't see where I made a mistake.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
    int num = Console.Read();
    Console.WriteLine();
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        int result = num * i;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", num, i, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `int num = Console.Read();` to `int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Its ASCII equvalent value of 5

Comment: Integer conversion with `Console.ReadLine` works correctly here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UxbT5O.

Comment: I started with converting but it did not work. So I tried without it.

Comment: When something doesn't work as expected, you should first read the documentation of the function/lib. If you'd do that, you would immediately understand that there is no "magic" here. SO is not a substitute for searching trivial information with a web search engine.

Answer (score 7):

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Console.Read`. It returns the **next character** from the input stream. By assigning it to an `int`, you convert a `char` to an `int`, which yields the character's code.

Use the `Console.ReadLine` method combined with `int.Parse` instead:

```
int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

This will return the whole input as a `string`, and `int.Parse` will attempt to create an `int` from it.

Comment: Really, one should be using `TryParse` as `Parse` will throw an exception if the user inputs a non-numeric string. Something like `if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int num))`, then the rest of the code as usual inside and some handling code in the `else` block.

Comment: @T.Linnell Definitely, however, I wanted to keep my response as concise as possible, since based on the nature of the question, the OP must be a beginner and therefore I didn't want to add any otherwise unnecessary noise. I assume valid input in this answer.

Comment: @T.Linnell, you forgot to add logging and setup project ;)

Comment: @Balázs: of course, that's why I upvoted, I just wanted to mention it for completeness as a next step for OP to take.

Comment: @Sinatr: did I? The scope of OP's code is that it spits out a times-table for a given user input - the code they posted seems to be the entire codebase. I don't think logging would be necessary in a project that small.

Comment: @T.Linnell, it was a counter-comment. You [aggro'd](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=aggro) me with "Really". There are many things to add to any answer to make it production-ready. Your comment, while useful, fighting against another issue - how to validate user input, which OP have to learn by doing mistakes. I wouldn't say a word if you would post an answer with `TryParse` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use  Console.ReadLine() method;

```
 int num =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int num;
        //  Console.WriteLine();
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out num))
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                int result = num * i;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", num, i, result);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //not an integer
            Console.WriteLine("not an integer");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Console.ReadLine() takes all inputs from console as string so you need to convert to integer. Int32.TryParse()  converts string to equivalent 32 bit signed integer and assigned it to out parameter.Else, you know input is not integer. Thanks